# how modify message body - Mimekit Message

Tags: c#, email, message, mailkit, mimekit

i'm using mimekit for receive and send mail for my project. I'm sending received mails with some  modifications (to & from parts). And now i need to modify in body section. I'll replace specific word with asterix chars. Specific text different for every mail. Mail may be any format. You can see i found what i want but i don't know how can i replace without any error?

[image]

Comment: If the Text property is writable, I guess the only way to find out is to actually try modifying it.

Comment: yes Text property seems writable. But; MimeMessage mesaj; mesaj.body is not a kind of list type. So i cant access and modfiy mesaj.body[0].Text. I can't found the way of Text property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MimeMessage.Body` is a tree structure, like MIME, so you'll have to navigate to the `MimePart` that contains the content that you want to modify.

In this case, since you want to modify a text/* `MimePart`, it will actually be a subclass of `MimePart` called `TextPart` which is what has the `.Text` property (which is writable).

I've written documentation on how to traverse the MIME structure of a message to find the part that you are looking for here: http://www.mimekit.org/docs/html/WorkingWithMessages.htm

A very simple solution might be:

```
var part = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart> ().FirstOrDefault ();
part.Text = part.Text.Replace ("x", "y");
```

But keep in mind that that logic assumes that the first text/* part you find is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but in first line:

`System.Collections.GenericIEnumerable<MimeKit.MimeEntity> does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and not extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.GenericIEnumerable<MimeKit.MimeEntity> could by found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
I'm using MimeKit.1.2.0.0

Comment: That's a LINQ statement. You need to add `using System.Linq;` to your list of usings.

Comment: Ok, when i see mesaj.body in debug screen, it seems changed. But when i send mail, receiver take unchanged version. is it need a like rebuild or something?

Comment: There's no rebuild. I don't know why you are seeing the behavior that you are seeing. I'd have to see your code.

Comment: The problem is that your message has 2 copies of the message body. One version in `text/plain` and another in `text/html`. You've only replaced the text in the `text/plain` version, but not the `text/html` version. You need to replace both.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's working. Is BodyParts & Body different? Should i loop both of them? Or should i loop Multipart like TextPart?

Final Code :

foreach (var part in ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)mesaj.Body).OfType<TextPart>()) { part.Text = part.Text.Replace("@", "[at]"); }

Comment: `BodyParts` is just a convenience property that iterates over the `Body` property in a list-like fashion instead of a tree.